# Alias file not working in Bash on WSL (Opensuse Leap 42.3)

Tags: windows-10, vim, opensuse, windows-subsystem-for-linux, bash-alias

I have my alias file set up like so in Bash in WSL:

```
alias gvim='/mnt/d/Vim/vim81/gvim.exe'
alias vim='/mnt/d/Vim/vim81/vim.exe'
alias pngcrush='/mnt/c/Users/nathan/Downloads/pngcrush_1_8_11_w64.exe -reduce -brute -ow'
```

but when I try running gvim or vim within Bash, I get this error:

`:No such file or directorym.exe` (gvim)

`:No such file or directory.exe' (vim)

However, the pngcrush alias works correctly. For some odd reason though, the aliases defined in my ~/.alias file have the first "a" in alias replaced with single quote and the ending single quote is missing when I run alias command in bash without arguments.

Anyone know why the gvim and vim executables are not being found correctly? If I enter the path to the .exe in bash directly it works but those two aliases don't work

Bash version:

```
> bash --version
GNU bash, version 4.3.42(1)-release (x86_64-suse-linux-gnu)
Copyright (C) 2013 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>

This is free software; you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
```

OpenSUSE version:

```
> cat /etc/*release
NAME="openSUSE Leap"
VERSION="42.3"
ID=opensuse
ID_LIKE="suse"
VERSION_ID="42.3"
PRETTY_NAME="openSUSE Leap 42.3"
ANSI_COLOR="0;32"
CPE_NAME="cpe:/o:opensuse:leap:42.3"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.opensuse.org"
HOME_URL="https://www.opensuse.org/"
openSUSE 42.3 (x86_64)
VERSION = 42.3
CODENAME = Malachite
# /etc/SuSE-release is deprecated and will be removed in the future, use /etc/os-release instead
```

All of my bash aliases below:

```
>alias
alias +='pushd .'
alias -='popd'
alias ..='cd ..'
alias ...='cd ../..'
alias beep='echo -en "\007"'
alias cd..='cd ..'
alias dir='ls -l'
alias egrep='egrep --color=auto'
alias fgrep='fgrep --color=auto'
alias grep='grep --color=auto'
'lias gvim='/mnt/d/Vim/vim81/gvim.exe
alias l='ls -alF'
alias la='ls -la'
alias ll='ls -l'
alias ls='_ls'
alias ls-l='ls -l'
alias md='mkdir -p'
alias o='less'
'lias pngcrush='/mnt/c/Users/nathan/Downloads/pngcrush_1_8_11_w64.exe -reduce -brute -ow
alias rd='rmdir'
alias rehash='hash -r'
alias unmount='echo "Error: Try the command: umount" 1>&2; false'
'lias vim='/mnt/d/Vim/vim81/vim.exe
alias you='if test "$EUID" = 0 ; then /sbin/yast2 online_update ; else su - -c "/sbin/yast2 online_update" ; fi'
```

Microsoft Windows 10 Home 10.0.17134

Comment: Check if your alias file has CRLF line-endings e.g. with `cat -v[et]` or `sed -n l` (ell).

Comment: Change the alias to another name like: `alias wvim='/mnt/d/Vim/vim81/vim.exe'`. The vim alias may conflict with the Windows path and Linux path. +1 for this well formatting question.

Comment: I tried `cat -v ~/.alias` and each line ends with a ^M. Does that mean I need to run dos2unix on it?

Comment: okay tried `dos2unix` on the alias file and the gvim alias seems to work but the aliased vim just hangs now if I run it from bash using either the alias or the path to the exe but works fine when I run that exe from Cortana. Guess I'll remove that particular alias and keep the other two. Thanks for the help dave and Biswapriyo.

Answer (score 1):

Quick answer: just open vim from within bash.

The Linux distribution you are using with WSL probably has vim included. There is no reason to use WSL & bash to open a Windows version of vim.